# Pandas Merge/Join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `Bob` with Columns = [A,B] and A has only unique values like a serial ID. Shape is (100,2)

I have another dataframe called `Anna` with Columns [C,D,E,F] where C has the same values as A in bob but there are duplicates. Column D is a category (phone/laptop/ipad) that is defined by the serial ID found in C. Shape of `Anna` is (500,4).

Example of row in anna:

```
A B C D
K103 phone 12 17
K103 phone 14 23
G221 laptop 25 6
```

I want to create a new dataframe that has columns A,B,D by searching for value of A in anna[C]. The final dataframe should be shape (100,3)

I'm finding this difficult with `pd.merge` (i tried left/inner/right joins) because it keeps creating 2 rows in the new dataframe with same values i.e. K103 will show up 2x in the new dataframe.

Comment: if you have two matches in the right dataframe, you're going to get two results.

Comment: How do you want to decide whether (k103, phone, 12, 17) or (k103, phone, 14, 23) is returned?

Comment: I only want k103 and phone returned. the last 2 columns do not matter in this context which is why i do not want any duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if this works, I'm thinking of this while typing it, so I couldn't actually check.

```
   df = Bob.merge(Anna[['C','D'].drop_duplicates(keep='last'),how='left',left_on='A',right_on='C']
```

Let me know if it doesn't work, I'll create a sample dataset and edit it with the correct code.

Comment: yes it does, thanks. drop_duplicates solves the problem